# When is a Hankel matrix invertible?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, hankel-matrices

I would like to have some conditions that render a general Hankel matrix of the form
\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &\cdots & a_n \\ a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \cdots & a_{n+1} \\ a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & \cdots & a_{n+2} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ a_n & a_{n+1} & a_{n+2} & \cdots & a_{2n-1}\end{pmatrix}
invertible. Ideally, these conditions are exclusive to Hankel matrices. Thanks.

Comment: If it helps, determinant of Hankel matrix has its own name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalecticant.